# Missing assembly error when converting .pptx file to PDF using Syncfusion

Tags: c#, syncfusion

I have the following code for converting a pptx to a pdf:

```
IPresentation presentation = Presentation.Open(filePath);
presentation.ChartToImageConverter = new ChartToImageConverter();
pdfDocument = PresentationToPdfConverter.Convert(presentation);
presentation.Close();
```

However, when the code hits the line:

> presentation.ChartToImageConverter = new ChartToImageConverter();

it gets the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Syncfusion.Compression.Base, Version=16.3460.0.29, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

I have verified my web.config and the dll in the references an the dll is here with the correct version.

However when I remove the line:

> presentation.ChartToImageConverter = new ChartToImageConverter();

it works fine.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using different versions of Syncfusion assemblies (Compression.Base and OfficeChartToImageConverter.Base) to convert the pptx document to PDF. Can you crosscheck if the assemblies (Compression.Base and OfficeChartToImageConverter.Base) are of same version. If you still have trouble in fixing this issue, let me know I will share a working sample for your reference.
Note: I work for Syncfusion

Comment: I have checked the versions and for the version for assembly Compression.Base  is 16.3450.0.29 and the version for OfficeChartToImageConverter.Base is 16.3450.0.21.

Comment: You should use both (all the Syncfusion assemblies used in the project) the assemblies of same version 16.3450.0.21 or 16.3450.0.29.